# Winter is coming

Tags: discussion

Winter is here, grab your hats and other cool stuff. [image: winter bash 2020]

I got some dishevelled hair, a headset—which is called 'disciple' and some awful masks :D

I hope you're having a good time

Comment: Keep spreading positivity! Expecially in this moment. Thanks and have a good time tooo!

Comment: @Liiuc: Thanks! :)

Comment: I just came here today after a five day straight break. Had post-exam projects and assignments to submit. My streak also broke. I am trying to be happy whilst crying about it. Happy Holidays to you Void.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh: Thanks! :) Same to you.... Winter is wonderful

Comment: @Void There is no season as winter in the place I live (Mumbai, India). It is always hot and sticky here. Never seen snow in my life. It is only visible in North India.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Winter isn't my season; I hibernate until the first shoots of spring, but in the same festive spirit:

[image]

Yay matching flags.

Actually what I want to tell you is how pumped I am to see a lot of people pitching in and helping with the reviews. Very glad to see some relatively new faces/names here.

Comment: So far I’m still working on getting 10 hats